# Error while setting a tagging server in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to automatically provision a tagging server in GTM and I get the following error:

> An error occurred while creating the server. Please try again later. If the problem persists, please use the App Engine Setup Guide to set up the server directly from the Google Cloud Platform console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was a known bug on Google side, but it should work again now. Can you try again?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).